# I want to know pointer holds particular address at the time of debugging

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I got memory dump by using #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC in output window.

Detected memory leaks!

Dumping objects -> 
{1078301} normal block at 0x0AB2D840, 48 bytes long. 
 Data: <2 0 1 4 - 0 9 - > 32 00 30 00 31 00 34 00 2D 00 30 00 39 00 2D 00 
{975444} normal block at 0x08D21138, 36 bytes long.
 Data: < =   =      pa  > A4 3D C0 08 B0 3D C0 08 01 00 00 00 70 61 BE 08 
{975443} normal block at 0x0CE96610, 32 bytes long.
 Data: <,X  \       pa  > 2C 58 C0 08 5C 90 BF 08 01 00 00 00 70 61 BE 08 
{975438} normal block at 0x0CE6B1D8, 32 bytes long.
 Data:  50 90 BF 08 5C 90 BF 08 01 00 00 00 08 E3 D1 08 
{736753} normal block at 0x0CEAA878, 16384 bytes long.
 Data: < /   /          > D8 2F D2 08 D8 2F D2 08 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{736744} normal block at 0x0CEA8838, 8192 bytes long.
 Data: <8   8           > 38 0B E2 0C 38 88 EA 0C 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{736738} normal block at 0x0CEA47F8, 16384 bytes long.
 Data: <     G          > 00 00 00 00 F8 47 EA 0C 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{736729} normal block at 0x0CE105A8, 8192 bytes long.
 Data: <(               > 28 14 D1 08 A8 05 E1 0C 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{736723} normal block at 0x0CEA07B8, 16384 bytes long.
Data: < G  8           > F8 47 EA 0C 38 88 EA 0C 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{736713} normal block at 0x0CE1E440, 8192 bytes long.
Data: <    @           > A8 05 E1 0C 40 E4 E1 0C 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{736707} normal block at 0x0CE1A400, 16384 bytes long.
Data: <                > B8 07 EA 0C B8 07 EA 0C 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{736698} normal block at 0x0CE36B18, 8192 bytes long.
Data: <@    k          > 40 E4 E1 0C 18 6B E3 0C 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{736692} normal block at 0x0CE163C0, 16384 bytes long.
Data: <                > 00 A4 E1 0C 00 A4 E1 0C 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{736682} normal block at 0x0CE44230, 8192 bytes long.
Data: < k  0B          > 18 6B E3 0C 30 42 E4 0C 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{736676} normal block at 0x0CE3E7F8, 16384 bytes long.
Data: < c   c          > C0 63 E1 0C C0 63 E1 0C 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{736666} normal block at 0x0CE4B6F0, 8192 bytes long.
Data: <0B              > 30 42 E4 0C F0 B6 E4 0C 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{736660} normal block at 0x0CE3A7B8, 16384 bytes long.
Data: <                > F8 E7 E3 0C F8 E7 E3 0C 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{736650} normal block at 0x0CE47388, 8192 bytes long.
Data: <     s          > F0 B6 E4 0C 88 73 E4 0C 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{736644} normal block at 0x0CE0C568, 16384 bytes long.
Data: <                > B8 A7 E3 0C B8 A7 E3 0C 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{736634} normal block at 0x0CE20B38, 8192 bytes long.
Data: < s  8           > 88 73 E4 0C 38 0B E2 0C 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{736628} normal block at 0x0CE23B70, 16384 bytes long.
Data:  68 C5 E0 0C 68 C5 E0 0C 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{663741} normal block at 0x0CDB6EF0, 60 bytes long.
Data:  50 F2 BF 08 24 6F C0 08 01 00 00 00 30 75 00 00 
{1923} normal block at 0x08D20DE8, 8 bytes long.
Data: <@]  d   > 40 5D BE 08 64 C0 D1 08 
{1922} normal block at 0x08D22E10, 56 bytes long.
Data:  70 5C BE 08 00 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD E8 0D D2 08 
{1900} normal block at 0x08D27018, 16384 bytes long.
Data: <                > F0 E2 D1 08 F0 E2 D1 08 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{1894} normal block at 0x08D22FD8, 16384 bytes long.
Data:  70 3B E2 0C 70 3B E2 0C 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{1883} normal block at 0x08D22900, 144 bytes long.
Data:  43 00 3A 00 5C 00 55 00 73 00 65 00 72 00 73 00 
Object dump complete.

Now debegger hits the breakpoint. In watch window, at the time of debuging I add {,,msvcr100d.dll}_crtBreakAlloc in name columm and I add memory location 736723 which is the memory block number in the dump mentioned above in the value columm. This leak happens in a function that loops.

When I continue debugging, it breaks at the memory block number that is entered in watch window [see fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etA5x.png)
press break in the window 
see fig 2
 _CrtDbgBreak holds 0x69595280.thats where memory leak happens

Now, how do I get to know the pointer that holds particular address loaction at the time of debugging.

Thanks in Advance
Avinash V

Comment: Why do you want to know the pointer value? Don't you want to know where the allocation happens? For that you can check the call stack.

Comment: You probably should better check the callstack, and see where this came from your code. I'd guess this is the more effective technique.

Answer (score 0):

The program already breaks there, so you should go the call stack window in Visual studio and  find the source code there, then you can find the source code which calls the memory allocation function, that is  what you're looking for.

As you're using the allocation number to tracking memory leaks, the allocation number can change if the program doesn't run under previous conditions. Please refer: [Finding Memory Leaks Using the CRT Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx)

Comment: I go the call stack window in Visual studio and find the source code there, then you can find the source code which calls the memory allocation function, that is what you're looking for.

Comment: I go the call stack window in Visual studio and find the source code there, then you can find the source code which calls the memory allocation function, that is what you're looking for.

Some times call stack does not have any code related to my code.

What can i do at that time.

Some times call stack does have code related to my code.
But it does not correct location.


If it is is possible i want to see all variables those have active life time at particular point.

Thanks in Advance Avinash V.